# is there a way to set variable type in PUG mixin?

Tags: intellij-idea, types, pug

I have a warning in my pug file (ideaj ide)

I like typing... ;)

But I can't reach any information how to accomplish typing in the PUG syntax.

I tried few syntaxes jsdoc, typescript, flowtype, c, java like - all ends with hard error.

[image: variable has no type]

Comment: Your image is broken.

Comment: link fixed (hope imgur is more stable than dropbox) ;)